# How to do intersect, union, etc. on ordered pairs?

Tags: r

Is there a set of R functions analogous to `intersect`, `union`, etc. which act on vectors of coordinates?  Take a two collections of locations in N dimensions, each of  which could be viewed as N-row by M-location array, and find the common locations (i.e. columns), and so on.  I suppose this could be done with a couple `*apply` lines to compare every column in one array to the columns of the other, but was hoping for something faster or neater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 'sets' package, but the simplest solution would be to use the base set operations: `union`, , `intersect` , and  `setdiff` on the results of `paste` with a separator such as `"_"`. If these are represented as 'numeric" values you may need to make decsions about what really means "equality" and for that some `round`-ing or `trunc`-cation may be needed.

Another thought is that implementation might be more self-documenting in the columnwise arrangement you describe to use the "plyr" function:`colwise`. I'm not a dedicated user of plyr methods, but this appears to be how it might start:

```
colpastefn <- colwise( function(...){paste(... , sep="_") )
```

Although the description of the function suggests it should work as a standalone function on a dataframe, all of the illustrated uses are with `ddply`.

Comment: Works for me.  I certainly agree that an intelligent experimentalist :-) would want to `trunc` his values before deciding which locations were identical.  I'll check this answer unless someone comes up with something spectacular in the near future.